# How to use double in a for loop rather than an int?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am wondering how to make a `for loop` use a `double` variable, instead of an `int`.
What I've tried, only produced a `double`, but it was basically an `int` with a ".0" 
behind each number.

**Code:**

```
public static void FindTheDouble() {

    double LookFor = 2.29195;
                            //also tried adding a ".xxx" here
    for (double i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { //notice i is of type double
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i == LookFor) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Found the double: "+LookFor);
            break;          
        }   
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to say what I was looking for. I was looking for it to go through ".xxxxxxx", but just got that output.

And is that a proper way of using a `break` statement? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: In your for loop you can replace i++ with whatever you want...i.e. i+=0.1345 if you want to have decimal places for some reason. You are using the break statement correctly.

Comment: It’s not clear what “make a for loop a double” means.  Why would you expect the values to be anything other than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: It's possible to literally iterate through every possible `double` value using `Math.ulp` or `Double.longBitsToDouble` but this would take a very long time and I can't help but think there must be a better way to do what you want to do. Maybe if you told us more about what you want to achieve we could suggest a better way.

Comment: Your iteration variable is indeed a double, but you're setting it to 1 and then incrementing it by 1 each time through the loop.  So even though the variable type is double, it will still only contain floating point equivalents of those integers.  If you want non-integral values then you will need to increment by a non-integral value.

Comment: @paisanco I didn't see that question in my search, this is my second question I have ever asked on this site.

Comment: @mba12 Okay, I didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: @RJM Thanks, I am a newbie to java, so still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void FindTheDouble() {

double LookFor = 2.29195;

for (double i = 1.0; i <= 5.0; i+=0.00005) {
    System.out.println(i);
       if (i == LookFor) {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Found the double: "+LookFor);
           break;          
       }   
   }
}
```

Your break statement is correct.

Your equality statement might fail with doubles. Instead you want to do something like this:

```
if (Math.abs((i - LookFor)) < 0.0000001)
```

The double can have extraneous values at extended decimal places that can interfere with the success of your equality comparison. Instead it is better to check that the two double values are within some degree of precision that is acceptable to you.

Comment: Beware the pitfall of multiple increments to a floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Rest assured that `i` *is* a `double`, but `i` will never be `2.29195`.

Using a `double` in a `for` loop requires careful consideration since repeated addition of a constant to a floating point can cause accumulating total to "go off" due to inexact conversions from decimal to binary. (Try it with `i += 0.1` as the incrementation and see for yourself). But for small whole numbers you'd be absolutely fine although then the use of a `double` is, of course, pointless.

If you want to effectively count up by units of 0.00001 then use something like

```
for (int i = 100000; i <= 500000; ++i){
    double f = i * 0.00001;
}
```

Then `f` is as close to the number that you really want as an IEEE754 `double` allows.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try that, and will take that into consideration.

Comment: just curious @Bathsheba what is the difference between `double f = i * 0.00001;` and my solution in top `(double) i` ?

Comment: In my case `i` is an `int`, and multiplication by `0.00001` not only promotes `i` to `double` but also scales the incrementation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to walk your double number each 0.000001 until you find 2.29195, simply add 0.000001 to i at each interaction:

```
double LookFor = 2.29195;

    for (double i = 1; i <= 5; i += 0.00001) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i == LookFor) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Found the double: "+LookFor);
            break;          
        }   
    }
}
```

Not knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve, instead of using `break` you cloud use a while clause:

```
double LookFor = 2.29195;
double i = 1;
while(i != LookFor && i <= 5){
    System.out.println(i);
    i += 0.00001;
}
System.out.println("Found the double: "+LookFor);
```

Last, consider user `BigDecimal` instead of double to prevent drifting float issues.

Comment: Beware the pitfall of multiple increments to a floating point.

Comment: Yes, I was wanting it to "walk" the "scale". I'll try that.

Comment: If this is to be implemented, remove the System.out.println(i) for each new value "i" takes. It'll spam the console. Perhaps only print in intervals, like when you reach 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 etc

Comment: Nice catch @Bathsheba I edited your tip into the answer.

Comment: @Raphael: Have an upvote. BigDecimal can come to the rescue here, at the expense of performance perhaps. I actually answered the question thinking it was C++. Silly old cat.

Comment: This one has worked the best so far, I need to edit it a little, because it will always say it "Found" it.

Comment: @OskarEmilsson I am wanting it to spam, lol. Thanks though. I'm using eclipse, so not a big problem.

Comment: this is the best answer. Remember to use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

About the final part of your question, a break statement terminates the nearest loop. For example, examine the code snippet below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < whatever; i++){
    for(int j = 4; j > 0; j--){
        if(i == j){
            break;
            }
         } //End of second for-loop
     } //End of first for-loop
```

The break statement in the code above terminates the second for-loop only. You can select which particular loop a break statement would break by using labels. Assuming I actually wanted the break statement to terminate the first loop, I'd just attach a label to it as shown:

```
here:
for(int i = 0; i < whatever; i++){
    for(int j = 4; j > 0; j--){
        if(i == j){
            break here;
            }
         } //End of second for-loop
     } //End of first for-loop
```

Note: You can use any word you want as the label; you can replace 'here' with any word except of course, keywords.

Comment: Mhmmmm... what is the use of `here:` I don't understand. Can someone _enlighten_ me? Thanks!

Comment: I used here as a label (or better still, like a marker). So, if I type break here, the loop nearest to the declaration (of here) will be terminated; in this case, it's the first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using `DoubleStream`from `Java 8`, you can try something like this, but please consider these points:

- Max. Digits After The Decimal Point Is 7 Digits (I haven't tested it for more)
- The More Precision You Want, The More Time It Takes.
- If The Precision Provided (i.e Step) Is Less Than The Target Double That You're Searching For -> It Will Not Find It (Normal Logic).

  ```
  import java.text.DecimalFormat;
  import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

  public class DoubleSearch {

  public static void main(String[] args){
      //Testing
      System.out.println(search(0.0000001, 5, 0.1)); // true
      System.out.println(search(0.0000001, 4, 0.01)); // true
      System.out.println(search(0.0000001, 3, 0.001)); //true
      System.out.println(search(0.0000001, 0.5, 0.0001)); //true
      System.out.println(search(0.0000001, 1.1, 0.00001)); //true
      System.out.println(search(0.0000001, 5.25, 0.0000001)); //true
      System.out.println(search(0.0000001, 2, 1.0001));
      System.out.println(search(0.1, 5, 4.0001)); // false because no enough precision provided (0.1)
      System.out.println(search(0.1, 2, 3)); // false as it's out of range
      System.out.println(search(0.00001, 5, 2.29195)); // your example returns true (i.e found)
  }

  public static boolean search(double step, double max, double target){
      return DoubleStream.iterate(0, d-> d+step).limit((long)(max/step)).anyMatch(p-> 
                      Double.compare(Double.valueOf(new DecimalFormat("#.#######").format(p)),
                      Double.valueOf(new DecimalFormat("#.#######").format(target)))==0); 
  }

  }
  ```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
true
```

Comment: I don't think I would mind, but I don't understand the suggested code. Of course I noticed the `System.out.println`, and the `method`. But I don't understand what you are doing with them. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Now, examine the code snippets below:

```
action:
//loop 1
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //loop 2
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        if(i == (j - 2)){
            break action;
               }
      }
   }
```

In the code above, if the condition in the inner for-loop is met, the first loop breaks because the label declaration (*action:*) is right before the first loop.

Now, look at this:

```
//loop 1
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //loop 2
    action:
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        if(i == (j - 2)){
            break action;
               }
      }
   }
```

Obviously, in this case, it's the second loop that'd be broken if the conditions are met.

Finally, there is no fixed keyword for labels, you can use any name you like (thunder, fire, superman, anything) and you can also declare multiple identifiers in your code. I hope this helps.. Merry coding!